# PostgreSQL math operations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have simple query

`select round((bca_total_lean/(bca_total_meta + bca_total_fat))*100,0) as lean_mass_percent from x where...`

as result, I see 0. for `bca_total_lean/bca_total_fat` result is ok. By bca_total_meta is 0.

All fields are integers and all results are greater than 0. The same operation in this data in PHP returns 83.
I also tried without a round function. The same result.
Separated data return by BD

- meta : 77391
- fat: 11892
- lean: 74362

Any hints where is an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer division truncates fractional digits. Your expression returns a ratio between 0 and 1, which is always truncated to 0.

To get "percentage", first multiply by 100.

```
select round((bca_total_lean*100)/(bca_total_meta + bca_total_fat),0) as lean_mass_percent from x where...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres does integer division.  So, I would express this as:

```
select round(bca_total_lean * 100.0 / (bca_total_meta + bca_total_fat), 0) as lean_mass_percent
from x
where . . .
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Let me understand why my example doesn't work.

Comment: @jaroApp . . . Is there some part of "integer division" that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select round((bca_total_lean::numeric/(bca_total_meta::numeric + bca_total_fat::numeric))*100,0) as lean_mass_percent
from x where...
```