# How to calculate the percentage(%) in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.4

I am not able to calculate the % in postgresql
Below the my code

```
v_total_repro_count = (select count(pm_task_run_bug_repro_id) from project.pm_task_run_bug_repro
                       where pm_task_run_bug_detail_id = 605)--5;
                    
v_repro_count = (select count(pm_task_run_bug_repro_id) from project.pm_task_run_bug_repro
                 where execution_status = 'Reprod' and pm_task_run_bug_detail_id = 605)--3;
                
v_impact = select (5/3)*100; = answer  = 100
v_impact = select (3/5)*100; = answer  = 0
```

the answer getting 0 and 100 instead of 60%

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 and 9.4 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade to a maintained version now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL math operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827781/postgresql-math-operations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast value to `numeric`

```
SELECT ROUND(( 3::NUMERIC/5::NUMERIC ) * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want floating point results, you should use at least one float in your calculation, such that the entire expression is promoted to floating point:

```
select (3.0 / 5) * 100;   -- returns 60
```